# ThreeJS translate scene position

Tags: three.js

I've been working at a game which is set in space meaning that the player can move through the solar system.

The issue comes when the player travels further away, and gets Float32 precision issues. 
I've been searching for a few hours to find a fix for this, but nothing helped so far.

What I also tried was to rescale all the meshes to be tiny.. about 100 times smaller than their initial scale, but that behaves the same when reaching larger coordinates.

Another solution would be to translate the world position, not the player, which will do the job.. but I honestly have no clue how to achieve this without changing each mesh position.

I've also set the renderer to use `{ logarithmicDepthBuffer: true}` but that still wont help me.. the player model starts jumping, flickering.

I spent alot of time by trying to find a solution to help me with this issue, so I appreciate any kind of advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move your scene you can use:

```
scene.translateX(i);
scene.translateY(i);
scene.translateZ(i);
```

Where i is the increment from the existing position offset. This can give you the illusion of an first person movement.
This is a common solution to very large scenes.

Comment: `scene.translate` didn't helped me, but It gave me the idea of creating a brand new `Object3D` containing all the other meshes which will have it's position changed in the opposite direction the player navigates to.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, I am trying to help. Remember that Scene inherits Object3d. In that sense, it is an Object3d already with Fog, multiMaterial and autoUpdate added. You shouldn't need to do anything to use it as an Object3d. In fact you're just adding to your call stack and memory footprint by placing it all in yet another Object3d. I understand conceptually it's more difficult with Scene to understand the relationship of your solar system origin and camera position, but it's worth pausing to consider.